# Heroku ruby on rails deployment problems with assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have a ruby on rails application which I am building using bootstrap which looks great when running locally:

[image]

I commit my code to master branch on git and then push to my heroku master. When I visit my heroku URL I get this page :

https://whats-on-today.herokuapp.com/

Not so great. I can see there are some 404 errors:

```
 HTTP 404 - GET https://whats-on-today.herokuapp.com/assets/application-96ded6f70c682e6f9f3a1ae3eb283ae0.js 
whats-on-today.herokuapp.com/:16 

HTTP 404 - GET https://whats-on-today.herokuapp.com/assets/application-2b56caae7bd0b485593c1fca2397cc26.css
```

I have no idea what these css files are and why they exist. My application layout code looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "DemoApp" %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

    <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
    <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>

    <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
    <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '114x114' %>

    <!-- For first- and second-generation iPad: -->
    <!-- Size should be 72 x 72 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '72x72' %>

    <!-- For non-Retina iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android 2.1+ devices: -->
    <!-- Size should be 57 x 57 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png' %>

    <!-- For all other devices -->
    <!-- Size should be 32 x 32 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico', :rel => 'shortcut icon' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DemoApp</a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><%= link_to "Link1", "/path1"  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Link2", "/path2"  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Link3", "/path3"  %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <%= bootstrap_flash %>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <h3>Sidebar</h3>
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li><%= link_to "Link1", "/path1"  %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Link2", "/path2"  %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Link3", "/path3"  %></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.well -->
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody explain why the code when deployed to heroku looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Did you add `gem 'rails_12factor'` in your Gemfile's production group? [Read more info in the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems).

Comment: No I didn't know about that. I'll try it. Why is it linking to a CSS file I don't actually have in my source tree though!

Comment: The CSS file is being referenced in your layout. The hash in the filename would be the hash of the CSS file, that's something from the Rails asset pipeline. I suspect Heroku cannot precompile properly because of the missing gem, therefore you're missing the assets on production.

Answer (score 3):

Use a gem for rails 4 on production

```
gem 'rails_serve_static_assets', group: :production
```

or use a rails_12factor gem (This gem adds two other gems rails_serve_static_assets and rails_stdout_logging)

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: So does heroku assume production by default?

Comment: Yes, it is, production as default